# How to check a array of number separated by one space C#

Tags: c#

I had a string of number and its separated by one space :

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 . . . .
```

How to test it correctly ?

If it is. Will return **false**

```
1 b d 2 ...
```

or If it is separated by more one space. Will return **false**

```
1  3      5 3
```

Solution:

```
        string temp = "1 2 3 4 5 6";
        int number;
        bool result = temp.Split(' ').All(x => int.TryParse(x, out number));
```

Thanks @Selman22.

Comment: it's not clear what you're asking, do you want to check what?

Comment: I just repaired the question.thanks guy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use `Split` with `All` method:

```
int number;
bool result = str.Split(' ').All(x => int.TryParse(x, out number));
```

This will split your string by space and check if each part is a valid int. If there are letters or consecutive white-spaces it will return false.

Answer (score 1):

Use a regular expression to match the string with:

```
\d( \d)*
```

This means: a digit, then optionally 1 or more times a single space followed by a single digit.

In C#, you would use it like so:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"\d( \d)*");
Match match = regex.Match("1 2 3 4 5");
if (match.Success)
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
}
```

Comment: thanks guy. but it same split string until be blocked by more a single space!

Comment: Sorry, what? If 2 digits are separated always by 1 space, it matches; if you try to use more than a single space, it does not match anymore. Isn't that what you asked for? This is by far the simplest, shortest way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

```
string line = "1 2 3 4 5 6";
string[] array = line.split[' '];
```

If you want to ensure array elements are integers, you may iterate each element and do `int.TryParse`

```
for(int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
{
    int tmp;
    bool isInteger = int.TryParse(array[i], out tmp);
}
```

**EDIT**

First, you may do a simple check if the line contains more then one space char between numbers.

```
if(line.Contains("  "))
{
    return false;
}
```

Then, split into array and check if every member is an integer.

Comment: if you are going to do a TryParse, you could just as well iterate through the string with Foreach(char c in string)